# Databricks Python run notebook in parallel with dynamic arguments

Tags: python, parallel-processing, databricks

I want to run a single notebook in parallel with the arguments passed dynamically. I want a generic function that takes parameters (notebook_path,threads, array_number_of_iterations and arguments). The user should be able to pass theses parameters and the notebook will automatically run the notebook in parallel.

Example:

```
run_notebook_in_parallel(path, threads, array_number_of_iterations, arguments)

run_notebook_in_parallel('path_to_notebook', 2, array, argument_array)
```

I have written some code that does almost does this correctly, but the argument array literally passes an array like [0,1] to the called notebook - not a single value.

The only way I can make this work, is by directly passing the arguments in the map - I dont want to do this as I want the code to be as generic as possible:

```
map(arguments = {"id":str(id_array), "otherargument":1})
```

I have the following code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
df= spark.sql(f"""select id from xyz """)
id_array= df.select("id").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

arguments = {"id":str(id_array), "otherargument":1}

pool = ThreadPool(2)
pool.map(lambda id_array: dbutils.notebook.run(notebook_full_path,timeout_seconds =300,arguments = arguments), id_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current approach is that you are passing the entire id_array as an argument for each of the parallel notebook runs. Instead, you need to pass each id separately to the parallel runs.

You can try this:

```
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import spark.sql as sql
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

def run_notebook_in_parallel(notebook_full_path, params_array, other_argument, threads):
    pool = ThreadPool(threads)
    pool.map(lambda params: dbutils.notebook.run(notebook_full_path, timeout_seconds=300, arguments = {"id": params, "otherargument": other_argument}), params_array)

# Example Usage:

df = spark.sql(f"""select id from xyz""")
id_array = df.select("id").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

# Specify Other Argument
other_argument = 1

# Run the function
run_notebook_in_parallel("path/to/notebook", id_array, other_argument, 2)
```

I have not tried it, but try it and tell us.
Greetings from Paraguay.

Comment: I know this, but dont know how to do it. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I edited my original post, please review it!

Comment: Hi @ozzbetto, it does work fine, but is has the same problem i faced earlier, that I want to create a function called run_notebook_in_parallel and want to pass parameters, threads, arguments and actual array that contains the number of times it should loop.

Comment: Ok @uba2012 I edited it again and I think that's as far as my knowledge goes, I hope I have helped you at least a bit. :)